# Java stream to map nested collection values into aggregating function

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

```
@Data // lombok
public class Buzz {
  private String key;
  private Integer value;
  // many other fields
}

@Data // lombok
public class Fizz {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Buzz> buzzes = Collections.emptyList();
  // many other fields here
}
```

**This data model is set and cannot be changed.**

The application guarantees that each `Fizz` instance has exactly zero (0) or one (1) `Buzz` instance that has a key of "points". Meaning if a particular `Fizz` instance has 10,000 `Buzz`es in its list, either *one and only one* `Buzz` will have a key of "points", or none will. I will never have 2+ `Buzz`es with a key of "points".

I want to stream over the list of fizzes and if a `Buzz` has a `key = "points"` then I want to take its points value and sum it with the other "points Buzzes" in the list of Fizzes. If a Buzz key does not have a key of "points" we can default its value to zero (0).

Hence if there are two Fizzes like so:

```
Fizz f1 = new Fizz();
Fizz f2 = new Fizz();
Fizz f3 = new Fizz();

Buzz b1 = new Buzz();
Buzz b2 = new Buzz();
Buzz b3 = new Buzz();
Buzz b4 = new Buzz();
Buzz b5 = new Buzz();
Buzz b6 = new Buzz();

b1.setKey("flim");
b1.setValue(-1);

b2.setKey("flim");
b2.setValue(25);

b3.setKey("points");
b3.setValue(10);

b4.setKey("points");
b4.setValue(18);

b5.setKey("flim");
b5.setValue(-7);

b6.setKey("flim");
b6.setValue(100);

f1.setBuzzes(Arrays.asList(b1, b2, b3));
f2.setBuzzes(Arrays.asList(b4, b5));
f3.setBuzzes(Arrays.asList(b6));

List<Fizz> fizzes = Arrays.asList(f1, f2, f3);
```

Then I'm looking for a Stream-based solution that tallies up all the "points Buzzes". In this case the final value would be 28 since there are only 2 Buzzes in the entire list whose key = "points" (`b3` and `b4`) and their collective sum is 10 + 18 = 28.

My best attempt thus far:

```
Integer pointsSum = fizzes.stream()
  .map(fizz -> fizz.getBuzzes().howDoItellIfItsBuzzHasAFizzKeyEqualToPoints())
  .reduce(Integer::sum)
  .orElse(0);
```

My problem is in crafting the `map(...)` statement. How do I filter to see if the `fizz` we are streaming over has a `Buzz` whose key is equal to "points" so that we can map to its Buzz `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to filter the `Buzz` objects that have a key **"points"**. And because you have that requirement:

> one and only one Buzz will have a key of "points", or none will

That means that a single result is needed. For that purpose *Stream IPA* provides the `findFirst()` method, which is a *short-circuit* operation (when it encounters the first element it returns it and no more elements from the stream will be processed).

Note that result may or may not be present in the stream therefore `findFirst()` returns an object of type **Optional**. And `.map(Buzz::getValue)` will be applied on an *Optional result* but not on the element of the stream.

```
            int pointsSum = fizzes.stream()
                .mapToInt(fizz -> getPoints(fizz))
                .sum();
```

```
    private static int getPoints(Fizz fizz) {
        return fizz.getBuzzes().stream()
                .filter(buzz -> buzz.getKey().equals("points"))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Buzz::getValue)
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

**Note:** call of `getPoints()` can be written as a *method reference* in place of *lambda*, but I *don't* advise you to create a nested stream by putting all the code from this method into `mapToInt()`. Functional programming was introduced in Java, **not** in order to write convoluted implementations but to reduce the complexity of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fizzes.stream().flatMap(t -> t.buzzes.stream())
    .filter(b -> b.getKey().equals("points"))
    .mapToInt(Buzz::getValue)
    .sum();
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.